# What's a Perl regex to convert dates like 'Dec 26 2012 12:00AM' to yyyymmdd?

Tags: regex, perl, datetime, type-conversion

I've tried pretty hard to find an example of this particular conversion (these date formats) using Perl regex, and to no avail.  Can someone please help me convert dates between these formats?

```
Dec 26 2012 12:00AM ==>  201212126
```

The following was my initial attempt but it runs too slow (obviously, I used substr like 5 times which is ridiculous).

```
# Format the input time to yyyymmdd from 'Dec 26 2012 12:00AM' like format.
sub formatTime($)
{
    #Get passed in value of format 'Dec 26 2012 12:00AM'.
    my $col = shift; 

    if (substr($col, 4, 1) eq " "){
        substr($col, 4, 1) = "0";
    }

    return substr($col, 7, 4).$months{substr($col, 0, 3)}.substr($col, 4, 2);
}
```

Note: This is for work, for converting input files to a very large DB ingestion, and unfortunately python is not supported on platform which is my language of choice for scripting.  I tried making my own Perl regex, but I just don't have time to read up and figure it out while doing other parts of this.  I already wasted most of yesterday writing Perl scripts and learning on the fly for the rest of it, this conversion just it taking me too long.

Comment: A regex alone can't transform `Dec` into `12`. Aren't there any date parsing functions available in Perl?

Comment: Don't roll your own.  Date transformations are a solved problem.  There are many modules on CPAN to do this for you, such as the DateTime module referenced in the answers.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I advice you using module [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/module/DateTime) + [DateTime::Format::Strptime](https://metacpan.org/module/DateTime::Format::Strptime).

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;

use DateTime;
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;

my $strp = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
      pattern => '%b %d %Y %l:%M%p',
      locale  => 'en_US',
);

# convert date to 
my $date = 'Dec 26 2012 10:10AM';
my $dt   = $strp->parse_datetime( $date );
printf "%s -> %s\n", $date, $dt->strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M");
```

**Output**

```
Dec 26 2012 10:10AM -> 2012-12-26 10:10
```

Answer (score 1):

So, what parts of `Dec 26 2012 12:00AM` are interesting?

```
Dec    26   2012     12:00      AM
$month $day $year $hour:$minute $pm
```

So we just define the trivial regex, capture the interesting information, and put them into appropriate vars:

```
my ($month, $day, $year, $hour, $minute, $pm)
  = ($string =~ m{
        (\w{3})   \s+             # 3 word characters
        (\d{1,2}) \s+             # 1 or 2 digits
        (\d{4})   \s+             # 4 digits
        (\d{2}) : (\d{2}) (AM|PM) # the hour, minute and AM/PM context
      }ix;
    );
```

Next, we make the month numeric and use the AM/PM information:

```
$month = {
  Jan => 1,
  Feb => 2,
  ...
  Dec => 12,
}->{$month} or die "Unknown month $month";

$hour += $pm =~ /pm/i ? 12 : 0; # if $pm contains "pm", then add 12 h
```

Then, we build an appropriately zero-padded string via `sprintf`:

```
my $format_string = "%04d%02d%02d" . ($include_hour ? "%02d%02d" : "");
my $date = sprintf $format_string,
  $year, $month, $day, $hour, $minute;
```

If you have the ambition you can easily add timezones as well ;-)

This method will produce weird results when the input is like `16:00PM`, as this would output `2800` as a time, which is obviously wrong. If that could be an issue, do the `pm` correction only `if $hour <= 12`. However, that only matters if `$include_hour` is set to a true value.

Answer (score -1):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = "Dec 26 2012 12:00AM";

my %months = (
    Jan => "01",
    [...]
    Dec => "12"
);
$str =~ /^(\w{3}) (\d{1,2}) (\d{4})/; 

print $3.$months{$1}.$2;
```

Comment: This is a poor piece of code because it lacks error checking.  You need to check that the Regex actually matched before you start using `$1`, etc. Also, you should check that the three character string you matched is actually a valid month.  i.e.: `if ($str =~ /^(\w{3}) (\d{1,2}) (\d{4})/ and exists $months{$1}) { print $3.$months{$1}.$2; } else { #error handling }`